# Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Im having a problem with my query. I recently switched to PDO, which is kind of new to me. Now i need to use JOIN in my query to get data from another table without making two executions.

Problem is, i get this error:

```
Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object
```

I don't understand what the problem is. This is how my code looks like:

```
  $friends_string = "SELECT * FROM `friends` as F, `users` as U WHERE `F.userID` = '$sess_user' AND `F.request` = '0' AND `F.friendID` = 'U.id'";
  $friends = $db->query($friends_string);
  if ($friends->rowCount() > 0) {

while($row = $friends->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<br /><a href='profile.php?id={$row["id"]}'>{$row["friendID"]}</a>";
  }

} else {
    echo "no Friends";
}
```

Or for short, just the query:

```
SELECT * FROM `friends` as F, `users` as U WHERE `F.userID` = '$sess_user' AND `F.request` = '0' AND `F.friendID` = 'U.id'
```

What I want is, get all rows from friends where userID is session and request is 0. But then i want to get the ID of those friends in users so i can make a link to their profile. Note the `$row["id"]`

I appreciate any feedback, doesn't have to answer my questions, if you note any problem please comment it. Thanks!

Comment: If you execute this query what's the error?

Comment: Call to a member function rowCount() on a non-object.

Comment: No, execute the query directly on mysql. the problem is with the query, that it's not correct, and `$db->query` returns `FALSE`

Comment: Im sorry but how do i execute it directly on mysql?

Comment: Try print_r($friends) and see what is says

Comment: Else echo $friends_string and try directly in mysql

Comment: print_r($friends) showed nothing. echo $friends_string seems fine when i look at it. It looks for the right values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put back ticks around the `table.field` ... You have to put them around `table`.`field`

Comment: This actually solved the main issue. Now i just need to restructure my query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your query with this one:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `friends` as F INNER JOIN `users` as U ON `F.friendID` = `U.id` WHERE `F.userID` = '{$sess_user}' AND `F.request` = '0'";
```

And add this to your connection, it will show you the errors:

```
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // Set Errorhandling to Exception
```

Comment: Still get the error. Double checked the string and it is right. The values are there and it should find them.

Comment: echo the query, connect to your mysql server (`mysql -u LOGIN -p`)and execute it and see the error. Answer edited

Comment: Alright. Got this: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'F.userID' in 'where clause'' in

Answer (score -1):

IMHO!
I saw problems like that with PDO...
and...
i think it's more likely to do all with pure SQL but good then duck your head with PDO.